# Where do I point my freetype font loader to?

Tags: android, android-ndk, freetype, freetype2

I have successfully put my font onto the apk in the `assets/` folder of my apk. I'm currently trying to get the Freetype library to see the Arial.ttf inside of the folder, but it can't find it.

APK structure:

```
apk/
    AndroidManifest.xml
    assets/
        Arial.ttf
    classes.dex
    lib/
    META-INF/
    res/
    resources.arsc
```

Loading the font:

```
FT_Face face;
if (FT_New_Face(ft, "/assets/Arial.ttf", 0, &face)) // TODO: get font locally
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_INFO, "SetupGlyphs", "ERROR::FREETYPE: Failed to load font.");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assets are files on the development machine. They are *not* files on the device. They are entries in the ZIP archive that is the APK.

In Java code (most likely), you will need to copy the asset (from `AssetManager`) to a local file on the filesystem, then have your native code use that local filesystem copy.

For example, this activity, copies a PDF from an asset to internal storage, to be able to view it using `FileProvider` and a third-party PDF viewer:

```
/***
  Copyright (c) 2013 CommonsWare, LLC
  Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not
  use this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain a copy
  of the License at http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0. Unless required
  by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed under the
  License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS
  OF ANY KIND, either express or implied. See the License for the specific
  language governing permissions and limitations under the License.

  From _The Busy Coder's Guide to Android Development_
    https://commonsware.com/Android
 */

package com.commonsware.android.cp.v4file;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.AssetManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.content.FileProvider;
import android.util.Log;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class FilesCPDemo extends Activity {
  private static final String AUTHORITY="com.commonsware.android.cp.v4file";

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);

    File f=new File(getFilesDir(), "test.pdf");

    if (!f.exists()) {
      AssetManager assets=getResources().getAssets();

      try {
        copy(assets.open("test.pdf"), f);
      }
      catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("FileProvider", "Exception copying from assets", e);
      }
    }

    Intent i=
        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                   FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, f));

    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
  }

  static private void copy(InputStream in, File dst) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream out=new FileOutputStream(dst);
    byte[] buf=new byte[1024];
    int len;

    while ((len=in.read(buf)) > 0) {
      out.write(buf, 0, len);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
  }
}
```

In your case, you would do this work before starting your JNI code that requires the font. And, since the path might vary from device to device or user to user, pass in the path to the font to your JNI code, rather than trying to hard-code it in the C/C++.

Comment: So, I've got the FileProvider data set up in the manifest, but I'm having some issues finding my exact files. I used `new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "Arial.ttf");` to try to find the font, but that isn't working and neither is it when I add `assets/` to the first argument. Also my paths include `<external-path name="assets" path="assets/"/>` which could be the problem, I don't know. Where should I be looking for the font file?

Comment: @iHowell: "I've got the FileProvider data set up in the manifest" -- that's more for my sample app. Mostly, I was pointing out how I see if I already have the file in `onCreate()`, and if not, I `copy()` it from assets. You do not need `FileProvider`, but my sample app did. "Where should I be looking for the font file?" -- wherever you are copying it to. In my case, it is to a file in `getFilesDir()`, as you can see in the `onCreate()` method.

Comment: When I say, where should I look for it, I mean that I can't find the original asset. The one in my assets folder. I get a `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Arial.ttf: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)` error.

Comment: @iHowell: That `File` points to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), where you need the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, and deal with Android 6.0's runtime permissions. This is why my sample app used `getFilesDir()`, which is [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) and does not require any permissions.

Comment: Oh. I thought `getFilesDir()` was a method you implemented somewhere else in your example. Thanks.

Comment: For some reason, my `appContext.getFilesDir()` is empty. It is pointing to `/data/user/0/com.example.SanAngeles/files` though, as it should be.

Comment: @iHowell: How are you determining that it is empty? You cannot see that directory through development tools, at least on production hardware.

Comment: Log.println(Log.INFO,"SurfaceCreated", "Number of files: " + appContext.getFilesDir().listFiles().length);

Comment: @iHowell: I don't know what to tell you. You might post a separate Stack Overflow question with a [mcve] demonstrating where and how you are copying the file from assets.

Comment: Just got it working, I forgot I was checking internal, not external. Thank you for all the help!