# Gradle add Extensions afterwards

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I wanted to add the FreeTypeFont extension to my Android project so I added the supposed lines into my build.gradle dependencies but the Extension still does not get detected. I also cleared the Project several times.

build.gradle:

```
project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-box2d-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"

    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
}

}
```

Comment: Have you tried http://stackoverflow.com/a/38127197/2194831